# Graphql schema to OWL ontology?

Tags: graphql, schema, rdf, owl, ontology

Is there any tool available to convert Graphql schema to OWL/RDF ontology?
E.g

```
type Person{
     name: string
     contact: Int
}
```

Should result in something like
[image]

Comment: not that I'm aware of. But you can go GraphQL -> SHACL -> OWL: https://www.topquadrant.com/graphql/graphql-shacl.html

Comment: also, this would be rather ambigue - your diagram already shows one variant that I personally would not consider. I would introduce data properties at least for the name